# Customize formatted billing full name with a custom field in Woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

On one of my websites I use the Flexible Checkout Fields for WooCommerce to make 20 custom fields. Two of them needed to be a select/dropdown field. I wasn't able to do so via the plugin (didn't want to pay for it. Regret that decision now. It is horrible); so I used the first-name and last-name default tags from WooCommerce to make them into a select field. I use them to select the Mr/Mrs title before the name.

The emails now only show the first-name and last-name fields, as where I would like to have the first-name (Mr/Mrs title select) and my new custom field for the first name.

I found the code below in admin-new-order.php;
`<p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>`

as where `$order->get_formatted_billing_full_name()` will display the billing first-name and billing last-name.

Is there a way to display billing first-name and my custom field? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the meta_key for your custom field (for the first name) please?

Comment: The id of my custom field is billing_voornaam_1_24

Comment: I have answer your question… you can try it, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to replace in `emails/admin-new-order.php` template the following *(on line 28)*:

```
 <p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>
```

**By this code** *(where `_billing_voornaam_1_24` is the meta_key of your custom field)*:

```
<p><?php 
    $formatted_full_name   = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $formatted_full_name  .= ' ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_voornaam_1_24', true );
    $formatted_full_name  .= ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name();

    printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $formatted_full_name ); ?></p>
```

This should work if `_billing_voornaam_1_24` custom field exists for the order…

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't display the first name as I would wanted. Might be an issue with the id of the custom field, I guess. Have tried some other ID's from other fields as well and wasn't able to display the information.

Comment: you should check in your database in wp_postmeta table for the post_id (which is the order ID)

Comment: Awesome. I was missing an _ in my ID. This works. Great.

Second question; Can I also include this within the customer details? To display the right name above the address?

Comment: @Carina092 Yes you can include something similar in each email notification template kind… But you will need to adapt it to the existing code, which can be a bit different. Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAzet How would that be possible? I only could find the wp_kses_post. I've read something about the     woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields hook, but I have no clue what I should edit to display the title and the person's name.