# Edit customer details in Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Where does WooCommerce include custom fields from third party plugins?
I would like to edit the order to display all the fields.

In admin-new-order.php, I can just do this by placing the `Woocommerce_email_customer_details` hook above `woocommerce_email_order_meta`.

Only how can I archive this with the email my customer will receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data from [**this question / answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504347/customize-formatted-billing-full-name-with-a-custom-field-in-woocommerce-emails), this can be done with the following hooked function, that will allow you to edit billing formatted address data:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'custom_email_formatted_billing_address', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_formatted_billing_address( $billing_address, $order ){
    // Get your custom field
    $real_first_name = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_voornaam_1_24', true );

    // Insert the custom field value in the billing first name
    if( ! empty( $real_first_name ) )
        $billing_address['first_name'] .= ' ' . $real_first_name;

    // Hiding Last name
    unset($billing_address['last_name']);

    return $billing_address;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> For shipping customer details, you will use **`woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address`** filter hook in the same way…

Comment: Awesome. Nearly there as it still displays both fields. Displaying the billing_first_name is fine, but the billing_last_name shouldn't be visible.

Comment: @Carina092 Updated you can try it…

Comment: Shouldn't the ' ' include something? Tried it, gave a white page.

Comment: @Carina092 Sorry… updated again… No more white page.